# In Dijkstra's algorithm why must it first expand nodes with the current least cost?

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have read in other posts that Dijkstra's algorithm always expands the shortest path first. Why must it be implemented in such a way? Say we created a relaxed version of Dijkstra's that expands *any* unvisited paths/nodes as long as they have a cost (calculated on the previous iteration) that's less than infinity.

I have worked through some examples and have yet to show an example that fails to calculate the correct shortest path using this relaxed version of the algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expand *any* node, you would eventually find some path to the goal but you cannot guarantee that the path cost to the goal is optimal.

If you find a cheaper path to an already visited node, you would have to update all nodes from this visited node transitively, rendering your relaxed algorithm less efficient than the original one.

Comment: I understand that if we stop once the goal is reached, then the relaxed algorithm would probably yield a suboptimal path cost. But what if we assume that it must always run to completion (i.e. halts once every node has been visited). Would/could it still compute the wrong total cost from a source to a destination?

Comment: if you happen to visit any one node on a more expensive path the first time you visit it, and do not update the cost if you detect a cheaper path, you end up with an expensive total cost. Visiting every node once is not a sufficient termination criterion in this case.

If you **do** update the node costs, you have to update transitive costs as well, and these transitive updates would make your lazy algorithm more expensive runtime-wise than the original one